# How to nest select statements using the same column from table source

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with customer id, products, revenue and dates.

| id | product | revenue | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | milk | 5 | Jan 1 |
| 1 | bread | 5 | Feb 1 |
| 1 | vegetables | 5 | Jan 15 |
| 1 | fruits | 5 | Feb 15 |
| 2 | milk | 5 | Mar 1 |
| 2 | bread | 5 | Mar 15 |
| 2 | fruits | 5 | Jan 15 |
| 3 | milk | 5 | Jan 1 |
| 3 | bread | 5 | Mar 1 |
| 3 | vegetables | 5 | Feb 1 |
| 3 | fruits | 5 | Mar 15 |

I want to group all revenue by month for all customers and also want a special column for milk revenue. So the result would be:

| id | month | revenue (all) | revenue (milk) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | Feb | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | Mar | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Jan | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | Feb | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Mar | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | Jan | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | Feb | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | Mar | 10 | 0 |

Here is my code so far:

```
with results as  (
  select table.id,
         table.date,
         table.revenue as all_revenue_by_customer_by_month
  from (
    select table.revenue as milk_revenue_by_customer_by_month
    where product in ('milk') 
    from table
 )
 where date >= '2022-01-01' 
   and revenue != 0
  group by date, id, milk_revenue_by_customer_by_month,              
           all_revenue_by_customer_by_month
  order by id
)
select * 
from results
```

Very new to sql and not sure what I'm doing wrong but I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional `sum` with `filter` and group by `id` and `month`.

```sql
with the_table(id, product, revenue, "date") as 
(
values
(1,'milk',5,'Jan 1 2022'::date),
(1,'bread',5,'Feb 1 2022'),
(1,'vegetables',5,'Jan 15 2022'),
(1,'fruits',5,'Feb 15 2022'),
(2,'milk',5,'Mar 1 2022'),
(2,'bread',5,'Mar 15 2022'),
(2,'fruits',5,'Jan 15 2022'),
(3,'milk',5,'Jan 1 2022'),
(3,'bread',5,'Mar 1 2022'),
(3,'vegetables',5,'Feb 1 2022'),
(3,'fruits',5,'Mar 15 2022') 
) -- mimic of the real data table

select id, date_trunc('month', "date")::date "month", 
    sum(revenue) "revenue (all)",
    sum(revenue) filter (where product = 'milk') "revenue (milk)" 
from the_table
group by id, "month" order by id, "month";
```

| id | month | revenue (all) | revenue (milk) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 2022-02-01 | 5 |  |
| 3 | 2022-03-01 | 10 |  |

Comment: It didn't work. I'm getting quite a few syntax errors but I think they are coming from a few differences. 
1. I am pulling the table dynamically so I don't need to define it. I can simply enter the from [address] and it works well.
2. I have more than one product on the real table so I'm using ```where product in ("milk", "oranges", "eggs", etc)```

Comment: Here is my code

` select table.id, 
table.month,
    sum(table.revenue) "revenue (all)",
    sum(table.revenue) filter (where product in ("milk", "oranges", "eggs") "revenue (selected_products)"
from table
group by id, month order by id, month; `

Comment: Yes, there are trivial syntax errors. 'table' is a reserved word and can not be used as a name w/o double quotes. Text literals must be enclosed in single quotes. One closing bracket is missing. "date" must be truncated to month and cast as date, Here it is corrected. `select id, date_trunc('month', "date")::date "month", 
       sum(revenue) "revenue (all)", 
       sum(revenue) filter (where product in ('milk', 'oranges', 'eggs')) "revenue (selected_products)" 
       from "table" group by id, "month" order by id, "month";'

Comment: Still getting about the same error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 30 unexpected '('. 
That parentheses comes right before the `where product in...`

Comment: You are making changes that violate the syntax rules. The queries above work just fine.

Comment: I copy/pasted what you shared.